# Avoiding global variables?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, global-variables, sidebar, google-sheets-api

This code works exactly as I need it to, how can I avoid global variables usage though ?

Global variable 'xxbtnDataxx' declared in *btnText()*.

```
/**
* Run initializations on sidebar load.
*/

$(function() {
// Assign handler functions to sidebar elements here, if needed.
$(document).on('click', '.qsbutton',function(){
var clickedID = this.value;
btnAction(clickedID);
});

// Call the server here to retrieve any information needed to build
// the dialog, if necessary.
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(btnText).getBtnData();

});

function btnText(value) {
var btnData = value
xxbtnDataxx = value
var selector = '#quick-shift-button'
for (var i=0,j=btnData.length; i<j;i++) {
      $(selector+i).text(btnData[i][0]);   
  }
}

function btnAction(id) {
var start = xxbtnDataxx[id][1];
var finish = xxbtnDataxx[id][2];
var shift = [[start,finish]];
google.script.run.setShift(shift);
}    
</script>
```

Comment: If it were indeed a global variable, `xxbtnDataxx` would be declared outside of the function. Based on how it's assigned a value without `var`, I think that is the case; you just misspoke. You're not declaring it in `btnText`, you're initializing it.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping it simple :

```
`a = 0`
```

The code above gives a global scope variable

```
`var a = 0;`
```

This code will give a variable to be used in the current scope, and under it

```
`window.a = 0;`
```

This generally is same as the global variable.

**EDIT**
global in the file ?

```
xxbtnDataxx = value;//on top

/**
* Run initializations on sidebar load.
*/

$(function() {
// Assign handler functions to sidebar elements here, if needed.
$(document).on('click', '.qsbutton',function(){
var clickedID = this.value;
btnAction(clickedID);
});

// Call the server here to retrieve any information needed to build
// the dialog, if necessary.
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(btnText).getBtnData();

});

function btnText(value) {
var btnData = value;
var selector = '#quick-shift-button'
for (var i=0,j=btnData.length; i<j;i++) {
      $(selector+i).text(btnData[i][0]);   
  }
}

function btnAction(id) {
var start = xxbtnDataxx[id][1];
var finish = xxbtnDataxx[id][2];
var shift = [[start,finish]];
google.script.run.setShift(shift);
}    
</script>
```

Comment: So the data I wan't to store for use with my buttons comes back from the server through google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(btnText).getBtnData(); then goes into the btnData(value). The reason I change it in there to xxbtnDataxx is because it's the the only way I found that lets me use it again in the btnAction function. If i put xxbtnDataxx = value; at the top as you say how would it receive the value?

Answer (score 0):

One way to avoid global variables that I have found useful is wrap all your functions into a "class". That way you can scope your variables "globally" inside your class only.

## Update

```
var Handler = function(){

var xxbtnDataxx = false;
var self = this;

this.init = function(){
    
    // Assign handler functions to sidebar elements here, if needed.
    $(document).on('click', '.qsbutton',function(){
        var clickedID = this.value;
        self.btnAction(clickedID);
    });
    
    // Call the server here to retrieve any information needed to build
    // the dialog, if necessary.
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(self.btnText).getBtnData();
};

this.btnAction = function (id) {
    var start = xxbtnDataxx[id][1];
    var finish = xxbtnDataxx[id][2];
    var shift = [[start,finish]];
    google.script.run.setShift(shift);
};

this.btnText = function (value) {
    var btnData = value;
    xxbtnDataxx = value;
    var selector = '#quick-shift-button';
    for (var i=0,j=btnData.length; i<j;i++) {
          $(selector+i).text(btnData[i][0]);   
    }
}
};

// Create an instance of the object
var handler = new Handler();

$(function() {
    // Call the init method on the class. Kinda 'ctor'
    handler.init();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Alejandro. Yes this is similar to the stuff I've been trying to get my head around but I can't get it to work in my code.

Comment: Yes that works, without a problem. The challenge now is for me to understand why it works. Many thanks Alejandro, it is much appreciated.

Comment: @dared, did I answer your question? if so, I'd really appreciate you mark my answer. Thanks